# Problem with the simulation of dji matrice 100 with ros

Tags: ros, dji-sdk

I'm trying to use ROS with dji matrice 100, i followed the tutorial on the website and i connected the drone and got the correct parameters. The problem is that i cannot run simulation and give commands because the signal of the gps is low. I'm working in a small office with a notebook and a pc desktop connected to the drone, is there a way to bypass the gps and run the simulation, or the only solution is to move in a place where gps signal is high?

Another question is how can i put my program (wrote in python using ros) on the drone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Another question is how can i put my program (wrote in python using
>   ros) on the drone?

I assume you're referring to controlling the drone with your ROS program without a simulator?

You need to connect the drone to a PC using the UART port on the M100. My setup involves a USB to serial Cable which is connected to a JETSON TX1. If you're using ROS, edit the details of the `sdk.launch` [here](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Onboard-SDK-ROS/blob/3.7/dji_sdk/launch/sdk.launch). Your PC needs to be small enough to fit on the drone. A raspberry pi will do the trick. For more details, take a look at the hardware setup guide at this [link](https://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/development-workflow/hardware-setup.html). I think the M100 + PC/Linux machine should work well for you. Good luck.

Comment: ok, perfect. So, i need a raspberry with ros on it and put it on the drone. To execute the program in the raspberry what i have to use? The remote controller with the ipad or another pc with the dji assistant2?

Comment: or maybe another pc with ros and via wi-fi i send to raspberry the command to execute the program?

Comment: @PaoloMilini is right, you need another PC to send commands to the raspberry pi. At the point, you don't need DJI Assistant anymore unless you're using the hardware in the loop simulator. You could simply just SSH into raspberry pi and run commands from there.

Comment: If i have the Manifold i think i don't necessitate the raspberry and i can use it for this purpose, is it correct?

Comment: @PaoloMilini that is correct, you don't need a pi if you've got a Manifold, they serve pretty much the same purpose for this use case

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can run and download the mobile (Android or iOS) SDK simulation example app to start the simulator from there and then run the commands you want from the onboard sdk/ onboard sdk for testing. I am not sure if this would work, since it is unclear if

1. you need to run the simulator from onboard as opposed to mobile

or if you need to run both two simultations

2. dji may not allow running two simulators at the same time.

2.) would be a DJI issue and I haven't testing 2 simulations at once. My guess if you can't run 2, but it could be worth giving a try. 1.) depends more on what you are trying to accomplish. But I could be missing something and don't have experience trying multiple simulations if that is what you need.

Comment: i need to run the simulation with the simulator provided by dji but i need to use ROS to send commands. After the simulation with the simulator i would like to try to control the real drone with ROS, but i don't know how

Answer (score 1):

Hi，did you open the DJI Assistant 2？You can connect your drone to the PC，then open the simulator of the DJI Assistant 2.In the simulator,you can set the latitude and longitude.After starting simulating,the GPS signal will be high at all times.
[image]

Comment: tomorrow i will try! Another question, is there a way to run simulation (and using ros to send command) without the drone? Or is it necessary use 2 pc connected to the drone and the ipad connected to the remote controller? Because i'm doing a project with my university and the drone and pc are not mine

Comment: Sorry，you must connect drone to PC，only in this way can you open the simulator.If you have the Vmware,you just need one PC.

Comment: ok, perfect. I tried to set latitude and longitude and it works!! How can i load a ROS package into the drone? Because i would like to try to control the real drone with my package in ros but i don't know how.